# Is there a way to trim all the fields inside .csv file using using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO

Tags: c#, textfieldparser

I am working on a C# console application. and I am reading a .csv file using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO package.
as follow:-

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Entities entities = new Entities();
        TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(@"C:\My.csv");

        parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
        parser.SetDelimiters(",");
        while (!parser.EndOfData)
        {

            string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
```

But can I trim all the current .csv fields in one place ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TextFieldParser` class has a [`TrimWhiteSpace` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.trimwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx), use that:

```
parser.TrimWhiteSpace = true;
```